# C++ pass iterator vs. pointer to function

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, pass-by-reference

I'm writing a recursive function that loops over a list of lists.
This is the header of the function:

```
void findDirToDelete(Directory*& current_dir_ptr, Directory*& dir_to_delete, int space_to_free) {
```

and this is the part of the function that is interesting in the context of this question:

```
Directory* ptr = nullptr;
for (auto it : current_dir_ptr->children) {
    ptr = &it;
    findDirToDelete(ptr, dir_to_delete, space_to_free);
}
```

This code compiles, and runs.
The class Directory contains, among other attributes, a `list<Directory> children` element.

My question is, why does that code above compile, but not the following?

```
for (auto it : current_dir_ptr->children) {
    findDirToDelete(&it, dir_to_delete, space_to_free);
}
```

This is the compile error that I get:

```
'void findDirToDelete(Directory *&,Directory *&,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Directory *' to 'Directory *&'
```

I have a feeling it's because the function is taking the first element by reference, but I cannot really explain why (sort of beginner here...).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First task is to learn to *not* use pointers. I don't see any reason in your code to use pointers. But I do see the need to use *references* more, like `for (auto const& dir : current_dir_ptr->children)`, and use `dir` directly and without the pointer-to operator `&`. Also that `current_dir_ptr` should probably not be a pointer either.

Comment: And please note that a [range `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) doesn't actually iterate over iterators. At least you won't have access to the iterators that the statement might use. In your loops, `it` is *not* an iterator.

Comment: Isn't your compiler error message sth about binding the reference to temporary? Always include the compiler error msg when the question is about not compiling code.

Comment: Please show a [mre] so we don't have to make guesses.

Comment: [Take a look](https://godbolt.org/z/7doejj3Ta) - it's the same as your code, just shorter. You cannot bind an rvalue (temporary, which is `&it`) to the lvalue reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function's parameter is a `Directory *&` which is a reference. It is a reference to a pointer, but that's a secondary detail, it is a reference before anything else.

In C++ a reference cannot be bound to a prvalue. In less formal, slightly imprecise terms, you cannot pass most kinds of expressions as a reference parameter. That's just one of the rules of C++, there are no exceptions or workarounds.

`&it` is an expression that produces a pointer. It cannot be bound to a reference.

`ptr` is an lvalue, a named object. Creating a reference to a named object is allowed in C++.